# How to download image from HTTP only if the image is newer?

Tags: c#, .net, http

I would like to implement the following functionality:

1. A C# client connects to an HTTP server and downloads an image to disk.
2. The next time the client starts checks if the image on the server is newer than the image on disk, and in this case, the client overrides the image on disk.

For me it's easy to download the image, but I'm not sure how to check if the image on the server is newer. How could I implement it? I guess that I could check the timestamp, or the image size (or both) but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching

Comment: Do you have control over the web server? If not, does it support caching, Etags, ... when serving those images?

Comment: Not sure how this would work over HTTP but you could try [FileInfo's CreationTime property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx). The reason I'm not sure is that I can't tell if the value of the property would be the actual creation date time or if it would be the date you last accessed it (I'm a somewhat ignorant on the subject). It's worth taking a look tho.

Comment: @Darin: No, I haven't. The server is remote and unknown. What I need to do is something similar to a proxy, or the navigator cache. I want to cache a resource and refresh it when it's new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpWebRequest can just use the IE cache, so if all the images will be in that cache anyway, and the cost of re-writing the file (but not having to download it) is acceptable, you can just make use of that.

If you need to handle it yourself though, then:

Given:

```
string uri; //URI of the image.
DateTime? lastMod; // lastModification date of image previously recorded. Null if not known yet.
string eTag; //eTag of image previously recorded. Null if not known yet.
```

You'll have to store these at the end of this, and retrieve them again (when not a new image) at the beginning. That's up to you, given that, the rest works:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
if(lastMod.HasValue)
  req.IfModifiedSince = lastMod.Value;//note: must be UTC, use lastMod.Value.ToUniversalTime() if you store it somewhere that converts to localtime, like SQLServer does.
if(eTag != null)
  req.AddHeader("If-None-Match", eTag);
try
{
  using(var rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
  {
    lastMod = rsp.LastModified;
    if(lastMod.Year == 1)//wasn't sent. We're just going to have to download the whole thing next time to be sure.
      lastMod = null;
    eTag = rsp.GetResponseHeader("ETag");//will be null if absent.
    using(var stm = rsp.GetResponseStream())
    {
      //your code to save the stream here.
    }
  }
}
catch(WebException we)
{
  var hrsp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
  if(hrsp != null && hrsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
  {
    //unfortunately, 304 when dealt with directly (rather than letting
    //the IE cache be used automatically), is treated as an error. Which is a bit of
    //a nuisance, but manageable. Note that if we weren't doing this manually,
    //304s would be disguised to look like 200s to our code.

    //update these, because possibly only one of them was the same.
    lastMod = hrsp.LastModified;
    if(lastMod.Year == 1)//wasn't sent.
      lastMod = null;
    eTag = hrsp.GetResponseHeader("ETag");//will be null if absent.
  }
  else //some other exception happened!
    throw; //or other handling of your choosing
}
```

E-tags are more dependable than last-modified when implemented correctly (noting sub-second resolutions on changes, and reflecting different responses due to different Accept-* headers). Some implementations are buggy though (IIS6 on a web-farm without a particular tweak, Apache with mod-gzip) so it can be worth taking out the code relating to e-tags and just going by the date.

Edit: If you wanted to go even further in implementing HTTP caching, you could also store the expires and max-age (use the latter if they're both present and it disagrees with the former) and skip downloading entirely if it's earlier than those values suggest. I've done this and it works well (I had an in-memory cache of objects created by from the XML returned by various URIs, and if the XML was fresh or hadn't changed, I re-used the object), but it may be irrelevant for your needs (if you care to be fresher than the server suggests, or if you're always going to be outside that window).

Answer (score 6):

Try `If-Modified-Since` request field. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
I am not sure that it is fully supported by every server. So if it is not supported and you will still get the file (and not 304 if it is supported) you can calculate checksums and if they are different consider file modified. Or just overwrite - and you will always have newest version.

Comment: Servers that don't support it are rare. You do sometimes find its not supported for every resource (e.g. ASP.NET or PHP pages don't by default, because it requires logic to know what date to send, though they certainly can support it), but all servers at least support going "sorry, I don't know, here's the whole thing" rather than choking on it. The code I give uses that, and also e-tags.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the [RFC 2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.pdf) and related RFCs (search for 1616 at http://www.rfc-editor.org/cgi-bin/rfcsearch.pl). In particular, §13 is of interest, *Caching in HTTP*, pages 47–62. Then read up on the related request/response headers and the related status codes you might get back.

You get access to all of the headers and status values via `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes.

But one should note that you can ask the server for whatever you want: ultimately it is the server that decides whether to send a new representation of that URI to you or not. You might want to use the HTTP [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) verb rather than its [`GET`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) verb to interrogate the server about the resource.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a
>   message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers
>   in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in
>   response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation
>   about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.
>   This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.

Comment: What use in sending HEAD? Either it's going to send a 304, in which case it's the same as GET, or it's going to send a 200, in which case the only way to be sure is to issue a GET after it.

Comment: HEAD won't return a body; GET might or might not. HEAD will let you invalidate the cached item without retrieving a new representation. Depending on requirements, deferring the addition of a new representation to the cache might be the preferred behaviour. Hence the conditional '**might**' in my answer.

Comment: But in the case where HEAD returns a 200, we can possibly know we definitely want to GET (different content-length) but not that we definitely won't (if they're the same content-length, they could still be different images), so we have to GET anyway. The only possibility is if someone is sending MD5 headers and not sending last-mod or e-tags, which is technically possible, but perverse enough that such person would deserve a slap, and unlikely in real-life (MD5 headers are rare, last-mod and e-tags are default behaviour for "static files" on almost all servers, and sometimes beyond that).